# Поиск упущенных значений в общей таблице БД

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем доброго времени суток. Попалась интересная задачка. Есть таблица Role с колонками ClientID и RoleName. Как можно найти в ней записи ClientID для которых остутствует RoleName ='User'. Знаю что общее число DISTINCT ClientID 897, а WHERE RoleName = 'User' 888.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была, что клиенты не были уникальными 
Написал такую кверю и нашел  все ClientID

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM Role
WHERE ClientID NOT IN (SELECT ClientID FROM Role 
                        WHERE RoleName = 'User' AND clientID IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ClientID
FROM Role
WHERE NOT RoleName = 'User'
```

Answer (score 0):

distinct во вложенном запросе сократит затраты памяти базы и времени выполнения.

когда тестировал 100 лет назад , оптимальный вариант был

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID  from tab t1 
LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t2.ClientID=t1.ClientID AND t2.RoleName='user'
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```